# ! Missing } inserted

Tags: packages, compiling, tabu, compilation-error

I'm writing a report in latex for school for several months and everything was fine. But recently out of nowhere it stopped compiling and give a lot errors like the following one:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.30 \begin{document}
```

I tried reinstalling the latex distrib but it's still failing.

Even by trying to compile a document without much inside it leads to the same error:

```
\documentclass[noposter,final]{polytech/polytech}

\schooldepartment{di}
\typereport{prddi5}
\reportyear{2018-2019}

\title{Title}
%\subtitle{}

\student{AAA}{BBB}{AAA.BBB@etu.univ-tours.fr}
\academicsupervisor{A}{B}{A.B@univ-tours.fr}
\academicsupervisor{AA}{BB}{AA.BB@univ-tours.fr}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\resume{RE}
\motcle{MC}

\abstract{AB}
\keyword{KW}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
TEST
\end{document}
```

Seeing that this fails I suspect that it comes from the class polytech/polytech that we have to use (which sources are available here: https://gitlab.com/MrCraftCod/polytechlatex).

Now the thing is that I didn't modify these since the time it was working and now. Plus if I use overleaf with it it does work.
So it must come from a package that have been updated and somehow messes up things.

Is there a way for me to narrow down the source of the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, welcome on LaTeX.SE! Thanks for posting an example. Have you tried making it even more minimal to track down the issue? (E.g., removing `\addbibresource`, `\resume`, etc.)

Comment: This class definitely loads too much packages... It takes awfully long to compile this until the error occurs.

Comment: If I remove the bib file the same errors happens.
Though I can't really remove the resume etc else the class will blow up to my face.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I do agree, a lot of things are not used. Though we don't really have a choice.

Comment: Just looking at the GIT repository contents, somebody changed the main class file and two other style files 4 weeks ago. I guess they screwed something up then. Try contacting the author, or find out how to revert to the previous version.

Comment: Using `\tracingall`, the error seems to be with `varwidth`

Comment: @alephzero It was me who changed things. And 4 weeks ago it was working and it works on overleaf. The problem started showing like 1-2 weeks ago.

Comment: @MrCraftCod: OverLeaf has outdated packages...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh where do I have to put this command to get the trace?

Comment: @MrCraftCod: Right after loading of the last package, i.e. in your case after loading the documentclass -- but be aware, it shows a lot of information

Comment: The compilation breaks somewhere before `\begin{document}`... either due to some package code or there is some `\AtBeginDocument` -- hook, which contains the error

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'd say it's from a package as i didn't change anything since a week ago where it compiled fine. I can maybe try to put a previous version of them and see what happens. The most recent packages are 
Package: fancyvrb 2019/01/15
Package: adjustbox 2019/01/04 v1.2
Package: multirow 2019/01/01 v2.4

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The error occurs in the first run already, so even before there is a completely written `.aux` or `.toc` file...

Comment: probably unrelated but don't do `\RequirePackage{etex}` unless you have a very old latex (pre 1985)

Comment: oh it's tabu, the tabu package currently has issues, we are trying to arrange fixes but it's not been maintained fro years and the author appears out of contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tabu package currently has some issues and the original author is out of contact, fixes are being developed at https://github.com/tabu-fixed but the internal documentation of the package is not that detailed.

Your example document works if you revert `array`, `longtable` and `tabu` to their texlive 2017 versions (just placing old copies of the packages in the same directory as the document).

That of course undoes the bug fixes that were made to array, but gets tabu back to a consistent state for now.

Comment: Indeed, removing the import of the package and commenting the longtabu part does make the compilation not fail. I'll see if I import older versions or try to rewrite this part in an other way. But thank you a lot to pinpoint what's the source cause. And thank you everyone that was involved and trying to help all along :)